# What are the characteristics of the 4 Yugas?

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga

What are the characteristics of the 4 yugas? What is the quality of souls in each of those? What are the other things which would be observed in each of the yugas as per the yugas? What marks the end of one yuga and start of another?

Comment: This question is a duplicate.

Comment: please see : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/what-are-the-four-legs-of-dharma/3092#3092