# Why did Sri Rama say that it is not possible to obtain fame and glory by conciliation even though the time period was treta yuga?

Tags: ramayana, rama, dharma, yuga

When ocean was not yielding to Sri Rama's request for 3 days , Sri Rama said the [following](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga21/yuddha_21_frame.htm) to Laxmana

> "O, Lakshmana! In this world, it is not possible to obtain fame, glory or victory at the end of a battle, by conciliation"

He then goes on to add

> "This ocean is considering me as an incapable man endowed as I am with forbearance. It is a great mistake to show forbearance to such an individual."

I can easily imagine the above to be true in kalyuga.

But we are talking about Ramayana period which was treta yuga (to be precise the 24th treta yuga of present Manvantara as per the Puranas). I understand that 3 out of 4 legs of Dharma are still present in Treta yuga as mentioned in answers [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/what-are-the-four-legs-of-dharma) - the four being austerity, cleanliness, mercy and truthfulness.  Thus I am interested to know whether the above statements are inline with what is expected in Treta Yuga - specifically mercy which was still present and only lost in Dwapar Yuga .

Comment: In Ramayana, there are a few places where surrender did not work. A surrender only works if the surrenderer is less powerful than the surrendee and the surrendee is merciful - both conditions must be met. in ocean case, first condition wasn't met. in dasharatha-parashurama case, second condition wasn't met. Thus, the conditions of both successful & unsuccessful surrenders (and the subsequent actions to be taken when it fails) are being displayed as a lesson to humanity. Source - Upanyasa. Can't write an answer because site only accepts online,written texts as source.