# Why would Kali Demon cause misery?

Tags: puranas, yuga, time, kali-yuga

It is said in the Kalki Purana --> "According to Kalki Purana, Kali demon will rule the earth and bring sin and misery to the people. When the first stage of the Kali Yuga begins, the varna system will deteriorate. Soon after this, the second, third, and fourth stages of the Kali Yuga begin. During the second and third portions, men will forget the name of God and no longer offer Yagna to the Devas."

But why would Kali demon rule earch and bring sin and misery? For what reason?

Comment: Very Good question!! Kali Demon is not causing misery to you. You are causing misery to yourself. No demon can harm you if you do not allow it. You are the Immortal Eternal Atma. Realize this and be free. The real kali Demon is the demon in You. This demon is causing fear, lust, anger, greed, shame, pride, delusion, envy. Kill this demon with the Help of Viveka (Discrimination) and Vairagya (Dispassion). Sri Rama who lives in you will destroy the Kali Demon with His Bow, if you have faith!! Please note that by 'You' I do not mean You. I mean generally all of us. All the best and thank you.

Comment: @Sai, small correction Viveka is actually *Discretion*.

Comment: @iammilind Well that's they way viveka is usually translated in the books that I've read (as discrimination). Anyways that's the last thing I want to have an argument about. I am no grammar expert. Take whatever makes sense :)

Comment: @iammilind I think discrimination is the more accurate translation - not in the sense of "America used to practice racial discrimination", but in the sense of "John has very discriminating taste."

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, according to Google Hindi dictionary *discrimination* = भेदभाव. However it shows 1 of the meanings as *discretion* = विवेक as well. Hence, I feel dicretion is more accurate. The former is more famous for expressing *partiality*.

Comment: I dare say from my common sense that Kali maybe does all this because he **wants to**, doesn't he? As he's like any other *jiva* (living being) out there, most possibly he is trying to get enjoyment living in this world...

Comment: @hijarian Well, that just pushes the problem one level up: why does he want to do this, and why does it give him enjoyment?

Comment: @Sai, KeshavSrinivasan, Recently I had come across many scripture references in this site, wikipedia and other sources. After reading those, I agree that *discrimination* is quite widely used related to (Hindu) scriptures. Still, I find it as a weaker choice to *discretion*.

Answer (score 7):

It's part of the demon Kali's fundamental nature to be evil, considering his lineage, which described in [this chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/8/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam:

> Another son of Lord Brahmā was Irreligion, whose wife’s name was Falsity. From their combination were born two demons named Dambha, or Bluffing, and Māyā, or Cheating. These two demons were taken by a demon named Nirṛti, who had no children. O great soul, from Dambha and Māyā were born Greed and Nikṛti, or Cunning. From their combination came children named Krodha [Anger] and Hiṁsā [Envy], and **from their combination were born Kali and his sister Durukti (Harsh Speech)**. O greatest of all good men, by the combination of Kali and Harsh Speech were born children named Mṛtyu (Death) and Bhīti (Fear). From the combination of Mṛtyu and Bhīti came children named Yātanā (Excessive Pain) and Niraya (Hell).

And Kali certainly lived up to his pedigree; [this chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/17/chapter-view) of the Srimad Bhagavatam describes how Kali was trying to destroy the last leg of the bull of Dharma.  (See my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3092/36) for a description of the four legs.)

By the way, it should be noted that the sinful nature of Kali aside, the Kali Yuga is not all negative; see my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2150/36) for the benefits of living in the Kali Yuga, such it made Vyasa shout out "Excellent, excellent, is the Kali age!"

Comment: Well said, I love Kali Yuga in some sense. Because this Yuga has seen the greatest of Saints and the process of Vedanta is now readily available to all who are interested. There are no restrictions. I also believe Kali Yuga presents the common man with the greatest of opportunity to be happy by developing detachment. What a better time to develop detachment than in the Kali Age, when the world is running around in rat races. Let us not miss this opportunity. Thanks

Comment: @Sai, some say that during Kali yuga, chanting the Krsna/God's name with true devotion alone is enough due to its severity! Keshav, from the blocked quotes, it seems that there are lot of incestuous relations between various vices/demons. However, *Mrityu* also happens for good souls including very gods, then why it was born out of *Kali* and *Durukti*?

Comment: @iammilind Yeah, chanting Vishnu's name is sufficient; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2150/36 As far as Mrityu goes, even if death might be a blessing in some cases, for the most part it's an unpleasant and undesirable thing generally.  That's why there's a demon associated with it.

Comment: @iammilind Exactly, in a lot of ways, Kali Yuga has a lot of positives to take away isnt it!

Comment: @Sai By the way, what do you mean by no restrictions on Vedanta?  The restrictions on who can study the Vedas applies equally well to Kali Yuga as in other Yugas.  As a result, the Vedantic path to Jnana is still restricted to Dvijas; all the commentators on the Brahma Sutras (Adi Shankaracharya, Ramanujacharya, Madhvacharya, Baladeva Vidyabhushana, etc.) agree on this, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8682/36

Comment: @Sai But I do agree that the Kali Yuga gives low-caste people and women more opportunities for Moksha than earlier Yugas.  First of all, there are texts available in the Kali Yuga, including Itihasas, Puranas, Agamas, and the poems of the Alwars which have no restrictions on who can study them.  Second of all, in the Kali Yuga there are paths to Moksha, like idol worship, the chanting of Vishnu's name, and the path of Sharanagati, which are open to everyone.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan obviously we have already argued enough on this topic. It is clear that you believe that caste restrictions on vedanta is necessary, while I don't. I personnaly conform more with some of the modern advaitins such as Ramakrishna and Vivekananda, who say that Vedanta is for all. Here is a quote from Swami Vivekananda I will provide some quotations in the coming comments. Overall, if you believe that the path of Sharanagati, which is completely vedantic, is open to everyone, then what is the argument here. :) Let all reach God just as we strive to. :)

Comment: Swami Vivekananda "The caste system is opposed to the religion of the Vedanta. Caste is a social custom, and all our great preachers have tried to break it down. From Buddhism downwards, every sect has preached against caste, and every time it has only riveted the chains. Caste is simply the outgrowth of the political institutions of India; it is a hereditary trade guild. Trade competition with Europe has broken caste more than any teaching." Source: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Works_of_Swami_Vivekananda/Volume_5/Questions_and_Answers/II_At_The_Twentieth_Century_Club_of_Boston

Comment: @Sai Well, you can call Sharanagati Vedantic, insofar as it's mentioned in the Mahanarayana Upanishad as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8709/36 But low-caste people and women would learn about Sharanagati through the Pancharatra texts or the Alwars' poems, not through Vedanta.  In any case, I was talking about the Vedantic path to Jnana having restrictions, not other "Vedantic" paths.

Comment: @Sai Concerning Vivekananda, of course I disagree with him, but it's interesting to note is that when he says "all our great preachers", I'm sure he would include Ramanujacharya in the list.  It's not that Ramanujacharya was anti-caste, but he's considered a great social reformer because he spread the path of Sharanagati, thereby bringing a lot of low-caste people into the Sri Vaishnava Sampradayam. You see, Sri Vaishnavas believe that once someone has performed Sharanagati, they should be treated the same as a Brahmin. They can even become priests in Sri Vaishnava temples!

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Well, ofcourse, I believe Swami Vivekananda does include Ramanujacharya on the list! Swami Vivekananda believed in the validity of all paths, and that includes Sri Vaishnavism. As for 'low-caste people would learn about Sharanagati through ... not through Vedanta'. How does it matter? Its insignificant technicality. As far as "I was talking about the Vedantic path to Jnana having restrictions, not other 'Vedantic' paths" well I disagree (as always huh). The path to Jnana is open to everyone. Our being Brahman and/or realizing it, has no restrictions which caste we belong to.

Comment: @Sai I'm curious: how does Vivekananda explain his disagreements with Adi Shankaracharya?  Adi Shankaracharya is considered an incarnation of Shiva, so don't Advaitins view his words as infallible?  Why would Adi Shankaracharya say "The Vedic statement, moreover, that the Sûdra is unfit for sacrifices intimates, because founded on reasoning, that he is unfit for knowledge also" unless it was true? http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/sbe34103.htm

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan This discussion will be continued in this chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26971/discussion-between-sai-and-keshav-srinivasan :)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever answer you all gave are analogical. Here is right answer:
In his past life king kali was a Gandharba. Gandharba means the children of demigods(demigods are in charge of universal administration residing in higher planets. So kali was a very powerful gandharba. He loved another damsel who was filled with all devine qualities. But instead of kali she preferred to marry a human, who was ruling over earth. (Kali had some other name that time). Due to this kali became envious and harrased them badly. The king lost everything and begged even for a piece of cloth. Finally the lady curshed kali to become degraded. 
So kali now came as a ruller in his age and has a aim to take revenge on humans. 
He have power to control orhers mind and he makes every human fight in the name of religion and color and kill each other. Do all wrong and go to hell.
Kali has only two weaknesses. One: He can not harm a person who regularly reads Bhagavatam. 2nd weakness is still unknown and hidden in Bhagavatam itself.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: Looks like you are saying people from all religions should start reading Bhagvat Gita?

Comment: @anant did you say nala and damyanti story?