# Why would Brahma create a son called as Irreligion

Tags: brahma

Somebody answered [one my question's on Kali Demon](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/6698/36) and said the following:-

Another son of Lord Brahmā was Irreligion, whose wife’s name was Falsity.

But why would Lord Brahma create a son called as Irreligion?

Why would any God create something bad anyways?

Comment: add a link to that question , it will make this question more clear

Comment: @Creator I added the link.

Answer (score 6):

If *dharma* is what God wants us to follow, if for the sake of establishing *dharma* that the Lord has to take birth here again and again (BG - 4.7), then what ignorance caused Brahma, the reservoir of all knowledge, to have a son like *adharma*? Wouldn't the world have been a better place if God Brahma didn't create this Son? Yes, it would have been. So what's the reason? Why would God create anything bad at all?

Well the thing is, stories of the scriptures are not to be always taken literally. Many of them are symbolic in nature and have esoteric meanings. For example, Kali has the wife named Durukti (harsh speech). It means harsh speech is the companion of the age of Kali just like a wife is a companion of a husband. So in Kali Yuga people won't won't be humble, instead they will say harsh words to others and will cause quarrels. Similarly, the mixing of *kali* (quarrel) and *durukti* (harsh speech) gives rise to death, fear, etc. which are described as their sons. In the very same way, *adharma* has been stated as the son of Brahma.

In reality, no God would create anything bad so that He will have to work for restoring the good again. No one is that fool. The manifestation of good and bad is natural and spontaneous because God is both *sat* and *asat* Himself:

> *sadasaccāhamarjuna* [BG - 9.19]
>    -  Arjuna, I am both *sat* (good) and *asat* (bad).

So in the beginning when creation occurs, God Himself enters the creation as good and bad and manifests as different material nature:

> *sa evedaḿ sasarjāgre bhagavān ātma-māyayā
>
>   sad-asad-rūpayā cāsau guṇamayāguṇo vibhuḥ* [SB - 1.2.30]
>
> **Meaning**
>   He at the beginning of creation through His own illusive power transformed into both good and evil. Although He is attributes less, He became endowed with attributes and qualities.

Then people as per their actions good or bad give rise to corresponding situations. Sages and saints describe it in many ways through stories and different philosophies. When one advances in spiritual practice through devotion, inquiry, etc. he will be able to know and realize the truth. The truth that, all is this merely a *lila* (sport / pastime) of God:

> *lokavat tu lila kaivalyam* [Brh. Su. - 2.1.33]
>    - The creation is merely a sport of Brahman.

I was also troubled by similar kinds of question, but it went away upon my realization of [Shunya Vada](http://shunyavada.com/) by following the path of devotion.

Comment: You said --> " So in the beginning when creation occurs, God Himself enters the creation as good and bad and manifests as different material nature". But why would God Himself enter the creation as bad? Was it just because God wanted to have some fun?

Comment: @user3750229 well, you can say so as you know about *lokavattu leela..* [Brh. Su. - 2.1.33 ]. But there are other reasons and meanings that you may come to know at sometime.

Comment: I still did not understand... GOD entered creation as bad just because he wanted to have some fun? And its HIS leela. And we are suffering because we consider ourselves as bodies and do not concentrate on our souls? If we meditate, even if somebody harms us, we will not feel anything? Then all of us need to leave our jobs and just meditate and concentrate on our souls? Who will take care of our families? Or we leave our families up to GOD?

Comment: @BeHappy as is evident from the comment of the person asking the questions, saying that creation of something "bad" is just a playful activity for *Ishvara* is quite irresponsible in some sense. Even if I agree with you. :) For people who don't know the context in which *leela*s happen, only dislike for God can arise. I speak from personal experience here. I humbly hope that my own answer adds some useful context to yours.

Comment: @user3750229, probably the author of this answer is on self imposed exile! However, I am quite able to relate what he says. The whole universe is created out of *Sattva (good, soothing), Rajas (bad, passionate), Tamas (ugly, ignorance)*. They are like Neutron, Proton, Electron of everything manifested. But there is also an unmanifested form, from which everything came & to which everything will merge. That is the supreme God. All activities are interdependent. When someone consumes non-veg, it's nice for him but not so nice for that chicken. Apply it to all acts. So, "suffering" = perception.

Comment: @iammilind Again, it is profoundly problematic to equate Rajas with bad.  A king who performs Yagnas and donates money to Brahmanas for the sake of going to Devaloka when he dies is a virtuous man.  He is not bad in any way; the fact that what he is doing is insufficient to get him Moksha does not imply that what he is doing is bad.  Sattva involves doing good for its own sake, Rajas involves doing good for the sake of the reward it yields, and Tamas involves doing bad.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, "Rajas" or "Rajo-guna" is indeed ***Bad***. In fact, among the 3, that's the greatest enemy in the path of self-realization. This is asked by Arjuna in BG 3.36 and answered by lord in [BG 3.37-3.41](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/3). Desire of Devlokas is fulfilled by worshiping Devas/Demigods; i.e. nature elements, brahmanas, needy, children. Hence you described is actually a *Sattvik Yagna*, [BG 17.4](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/17/4) *Rajasik Yagna* is actually worshiping the (internal) demons; e.g. lust (not Kamadeva), anger, attraction, superiority, rigidity, denial...

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, Rajasic has nothing to do with morality, it's just for sense enjoyment, let alone the Devalokas. In above cited verses also read the Sanskrit to get better idea rather than just translation (ISCKON isn't perfect in meanings). Thought of '*Rajasic Yagna brings heaven*' is quite flawed. Refer [BG 17.12](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/17/12) to see how *Rajasic Yagna/Yajna* look like. Rajasic Yagna are performed for some material benefits &/or hypocrisy. Lack of *Rajo-guna* is what generally makes chances of *Brahmana > Kshatriya > Vaishya* or *Purusha > Stri* towards God more.

Comment: @iammilind Well, I certainly agree that Rajasic people are after material enjoyment, but there are two strategies such a person can employ.  He can worship Yakshas and Rakshasas to get some short-term material benefits, or he can think ahead and conclude that material pleasures in Devaloka would be greater than material pleasures on Earth, so he would do a Yagna to the gods for the sake of pleasures in Devaloka.  I hope you'd agree that a person like that is acting in the mode of Rajas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, to generate any kind of desire, be it Moksha, Heaven, Hell, Earth, Lokas the *Rajas* is responsible. There is never a time in manifested form that either of 3 are not present. As soon as the (demi)gods are involved, the dominance of *Sattva* increases, hence *Rajas* is not dominant in what you said of Devaloka. Forgot the number of following 2 slokas where lord says that: (1) These 3 will be constantly trying to get dominant on each other (2) Rajas is meant for *short sighted or temporary or static* benefits. To understand, try to think Devas = Nature & Yakshas = Attachment.

Comment: @iammilind I certainly agree that Rajas is short-sighted in the grand scheme of things, insofar as even pleasures in Devaloka are ultimately temporary.  But Rajas need not involve immediate gratification of desire; it can certainly involve choosing a greater material pleasure in the afterlife over a lesser material pleasure right now.  But it's ultimately short-sighted, because the person doesn't realize that material pleasures are not a permanent source of happiness.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is based on wrong assumption that Brahma created this world for our enjoyment, and there is nothing else than this world.

### About creation

Bhagavata Purana, on the other hand, says that Brahma is being *born* in the specific universe and starts creating things after being *instructed by Vishnu* what exactly to create.

[Bhagavata-purana 2.5.11](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/2/5/11) says:

> yena sva-rociṣā viśvaṁ
>
> rocitaṁ rocayāmy aham
>
> yathārko ’gnir yathā somo
>
> yatharkṣa-graha-tārakāḥ
>
> I create after the Lord’s creation by His personal effulgence [known as the brahmajyoti], just as when the sun manifests its fire, the moon, the firmament, the influential planets and the twinkling stars also manifest their brightness.

You can read in the whole [chapter 3.6 of Bhagavata Purana](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/6) about what "Lord's creation" Brahma speaks here. After that, there's whole [chapter 3.8](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/8) about birth of Brahma and after that you may as well continue reading onwards. ;)

[Bhagavata-purana 3.9.43 says](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/9/43)

> sarva-veda-mayenedam
>
> ātmanātmātma-yoninā
>
> prajāḥ sṛja yathā-pūrvaṁ
>
> yāś ca mayy anuśerate
>
> By following My instructions you can now generate the living entities as before, by dint of your complete Vedic wisdom and the body you have directly received from Me, the supreme cause of everything.

So, Brahma doesn't do anything out of his own wishes - he's just a tool in hands of *Ishvara*.

[Chapter 15 of Bhagavad-gita](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/15) clearly states that there's something *else* than this (material) world. Krishna speaks rather succintly, because, after all, he and Arjuna are in the middle of the battlefield between two armies ready to fight, but he mentions immaterial world anyway, because it's extremely important.

Said that, let's talk about justice.

### About justice

Your question is "why would any God create anything bad anyways". But [*shastra*](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/9/9) says that God is above everything related to this material creation.

More than that, Krishna himself says that no one that ourselves are the reason of sufferings:

[Bhagavad-gita 13.21](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/13/21)

> kārya-kāraṇa-kartṛtve
>
> hetuḥ prakṛtir ucyate
>
> puruṣaḥ sukha-duḥkhānāṁ
>
> bhoktṛtve hetur ucyate
>
> Nature is said to be the cause of all material causes and effects, whereas the living entity is the cause of the various sufferings and enjoyments in this world.

Especially important is the verse [15.8](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/15/8):

> śarīraṁ yad avāpnoti
>
> yac cāpy utkrāmatīśvaraḥ
>
> gṛhītvaitāni saṁyāti
>
> vāyur gandhān ivāśayāt
>
> The living entity in the material world carries his different conceptions of life from one body to another, as the air carries aromas. Thus he takes one kind of body and again **quits it to take another**.

All this is to satisfy various desires. We have various desires, and some of us find satisfaction in illicit deeds, one of which is Irreligion. But for it to happen, Irreligion should exist, right? Somebody has to create the concept of it first.

But God wants from us different things:

[Bhagavad-gita 18.66](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/66)

> sarva-dharmān parityajya
>
> mām ekaṁ śaraṇaṁ vraja
>
> ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo
>
> mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śucaḥ
>
> Abandon all varieties of religion and just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.

This world is not for our satisfaction. It's to teach us that without God we will not be able to get any satisfaction at all. Some can be taught by simple thinking about God. Some - by hearing about God. But some can be taught only by experiencing continuous suffering, which will lead this living entity to the most important milestone in life - *disappointment* and finally, *regret*.

So, according to *shastra*, that's the most reasonable reason Brahma created such "bad" thing as Irreligion. He had to create *everything*, so living being could experience everything and draw a right conclusion.

### ADDITION: About suffering

It probably is worth noting also about the true nature of "bad". Even if the question started with Irreligion, it ended with more general notion of "bad". I'll show some more *shlokas* with the assumption that "bad" is something which will ultimately bring us suffering in one form or another.

First of all, [Bhagavad-gita 2.12](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/2/12) clearly states that **we are not created, we simply exist since time immemorial**, and Brahma is involved in our appearance here only by giving us the material bodies we are using and changing here.

> na tv evāhaṁ jātu nāsaṁ
>
> na tvaṁ neme janādhipāḥ
>
> na caiva na bhaviṣyāmaḥ
>
> sarve vayam ataḥ param
>
> Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor all these kings; nor in the future shall any of us cease to be.

This part of chapter 2 explains clearly that *we* as living beings cannot really be born, get old, get sick or die. All this is material illusion.

Nobody "created us in this world". [We](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/26/5) [are](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/26/6) [here](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/26/7) [on](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/26/8) [our](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/28/53) [own](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/16/57) [accord](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/22/30). We do not do here anything ourselves: everything here is prepared for us by almighty *Ishvara* so we would be able to satisfy ourselves, and while doing so we hurt each other due to our lust being transformed to greed and then to rage.

Comment: I am upvoting your answer for the efforts you have shown to collect the related verses. But you must understand that the asker wants to understand based on logic derived from these verses, which I see is lacking here. I find more alignment with the answer from @BeHappy.

Comment: @iammilind I humbly ask you to elaborate what *more* logic you want me to show in the answer. Because I personally believe if one just read the verses themselves, even without reading the Srila Prabhupada's comments, he'll inevitably come to the same conclusion as I came. So many shlokas is there only because I must cite sources and not the "logic". For "logic" one just has to accept a spiritual master and that's all - he'll answer all such questions easily.

Comment: I neither argue against those slokas, nor do I say that one should read Srila Prabhupada's purports/comments. I myself find them not proper. However what you gave is after effects. e.g. "Why he created *bad*?", You said: because some people realize god by continuous suffering that's why. That challenges rational logic. Because if I am the god and I create you as a soul and then let you suffer so that you realize me, then in first place I won't create you itself. Let you remain merged within me. Problem solved before it arises! :-) The answer of "Why he created bad?" is in "Why he created us?"

Comment: @iammilind OK, thank you, now I understand what is lacking from my explanation. As you yourself said (and I said it, too), to properly answer "why he created bad" we need to first establish some more context.

Comment: @iammilind "Because if I am the god and I create you as a soul and then let you suffer so that you realize me, then in first place I won't create you itself."  That's not even a conceivable option, because souls are never created in the first place or sent into Samsara; see my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3734/36 It's not like Brahman sits around thinking "Hmm, what souls should I create?"  The souls are already there in Samsara, going infinitely far back in time.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, mine was a crude example to explain logic of why even God should do something when ultimate goal is merger. Anyways, technically in this context I meant "create soul" = "manifest soul to an (subtle) embodiment". Often we have to think such rational arguments which are against the scripture to understand it better.

Comment: @iammilind But it's not like there was a certain time t=0 where Brahman decided to give a soul gross and subtle bodies for the first time.  The soul has had such bodies going infinitely far back in time.