# How should one decide his duties?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

In Bhagavad Gita, Krishna says to Arjuna that since he is Kshatriya, he should do the war and do his duties of being a kshatriya. Earlier we had brahmin, kshatriya, vaishya and shudra. And Krishna tells Arjuna that one should do his duties. But now in this age, how do we decide our duties?

EDIT: Lord said that the brahmins are the head, the kshatriyas are the hands, the vaishyas are the stomach, and the shudras are the feet of the Lord. I wished to know that since the lifestyle of humans has changed so much, how does one know his duties now? [This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/157/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-caste-system-how-has-it-changed) does not answer my question

Comment: [duplicate] of [What is the purpose of the caste system? How has it changed?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/157/2995)

Comment: @user5155835: The link you provided in your question does not seem correct as it fails to load. This is the message, "Firefox can't find the server at www.what%20is%20the%20purpose%20of%20the%20caste%20system.com."

Comment: @Jatin fixed it

Comment: @sv. I've edited the question, please can the duplicate mark be removed?

Comment: @user5155835 this answer http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/164/3500 gives you what was Varna system earlier. At that times Varna by Guna and birth were in accordance. Today's caste system is complex agglomeration of Varna-Jati System. In Kaliyuga Sudra Guna(Tamas) people become king(rulers). Lord Kalki will kill all evil Sudra Kings at the end of Kaliyuga. First three Varnas are "DVAIJA"(Twice Born), 1st time from womb and 2nd time by spiritual enlightenment. In Kaliyugas you will find very few "Dvaijas".

Comment: Also, look at [this answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9202/2995). _How does one know 'his' duties now?_ -- No one on this forum can answer that for 'him', 'he' should perhaps ask 'his' parents? Your question is essentially the 2nd part of question I linked earlier (_How has it changed?_), so I still think this needs to be closed.