# What is the current status of the four varnas created by God?

Tags: scripture, belief, caste-system

We all know that four varnas — Brahmana, Vysya, Kshatriya and Sudra — were created by God, and each varna’s people would mutually help each other, through the jobs assigned to them. But as of now in Kaliyuga, it seems that these varnas are mutilated. Are there any specifics for these mutilations of varnas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the caste system? How has it changed?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/157/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-caste-system-how-has-it-changed)

Comment: @sv., I don't think it's a duplicate. The question specifically asks about the reason of mutilation rather than purpose of "varna"-s. May be the questions are related. Other one is: [What does Hindu scripture say about class hierarchy?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11240/1049) (my answer was deleted).

Comment: @iammilind I think by 'Any specifics for these mutilation in varnas' OP means 'How has it changed?' He probably needs to clarify.

Comment: @iammilind Your answer for [Should a Brahmin be vegetarian?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8206/3500) answers this question.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, I doubt if that answer would do justice to this question. I will try to rephrase my deleted answer from above linked question here. Let's hope 'the mod' doesn't delete it.

Comment: The reason is Yuga Dharma .In Kali Yuga the bull of Dharma will stand on only leg.So as good as not standing at all.So how can u assume that the varna system will be followed in Kali?If Varna systems are followed rigidly how the papa purusha will take  command over things in this age ?how will the varnsankars be created?How will theworld will be destroyed at the end of Kali?If everyone follows Dharma, be pious then there r no reasons left for the destruction & starting afresh.

Comment: **In Kali everyone, almost everyone follows,preaches adharma but that is the intention of almighty,that is the way it is supposed to be, that is Yuga Dharma.

Comment: @Rickross In tghat case why the almighty is not punishing online the adharmic people? They are living happily than the spiritual oriented people.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan What a naive question!!..If all adharmic people are to be immediately punished and pious people are to be immediately rewarded then why is this Kali Yuga?.In Kali irreligion overthrows religion.That is the very nature of the Yuga.And this nature is determined by the Almighty himself because nothing happens without his consent.

Comment: @Rickross--I have not said immediate punishment--They should be punished phaswewise which is not happening. Everybody knows consent of almighty prevails. Neither you have experienced nor does not know what is happening around the world.

Comment: I think u have understood what i meant no point repeating the same thing over n over again and in anycase i was answering ur question"Why such mixture or corruption of varnas occur in Kali?" which does not appear in that exact words in ur question anymore.The reason is very simple -"strict adherence to the Varna system & prevalence of rampant adharma can not coexist",thats why.And i also assumed that by asking for reasons u meant such "root causes" and not socio-political,geographical or historical reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"But as of now in Kaliyuga these varnas are mutilated it seems."*

***Varna*-s are Not mutilated.** They can't. Because the *Varna* or "divisions" (not castes) are just descriptions of natural attributes. From Gita:

> <sub>1. ***Brahmana*** Or **Intellectuals**: Steadiness, control, austerity, cleanliness, tolerance, sincerity, knowledge, science and faith are certainly Brahma(na)'s natural Karma (BG 18.42)</sub>
>   <sub>2. ***Kshatriya*** Or **Patriots**: Heroism, brightness, courage, fitness, also not running away from war, generosity and kingship are Kshatr(iya)'s natural Karma (BG 18.43)</sub>
>   <sub>3. ***Vaishya*** Or **Businessmen**: Farming, cow protection (production), business are Vaishya's natural Karma (BG 18.44)</sub>
>   <sub>4. ***Shudra*** Or **Servicemen**: Services (in all fields) constitute natural Karma for Shudra (BG 18.44)</sub>

The term "Scientist" or "Musician" or "Actor" or "Businessman" cannot be mutilated. Because they are just "adjectives". What can be mutilated is the "entity" which assumes those "adjectives".
For example, "Newton family" or "Burman family" or "Kapoor family" or "Tata family" can deviate from their respective adjectives. If someone from famous "Kapoor family" chooses to go in business then the term "Actor" is not mutilated but the caste "Kapoor" is deviated.

> *"Any specifics for these mutilation in varnas."*

For many generations, various castes & ethnicities have assumed 4 *Varna*-s. **So the mutilation we see, are in the castes.** Due to this mutilation, you may see different kind of behaviours.

e.g. For many generations, the castes which earlier belonged to ... (in ranking order):

- "Brahman", are active in business & earning money
- "Kshatriya", are more into (wrongful) politics & hooliganism
- "Vaishya", are now active in (odd) jobs & research
- "Shudra", are similarly spread across other places where they shouldn't

This doesn't mean that everyone has lost the actual *Varna*. However, today one cannot decide one's *Varna* based on their surname or family name.
The good side is that, today's society is more open to allow a person to assume ***Varna* based on natural attributes, rather than legacy.**

Why such mutilation happens?
Usually due to too many wars & adultery, the **faulty hybridisation among races or castes** happens. Ideally the hybridisation is allowed among higher rank of male & lower rank of female. Any other intermixing is unwanted.
Here are some verses from Gita from Arjuna:

> <sub>BG 1.38 - 1.44 O Janardana, although these people, whose hearts have become perverted by greed, do not see the evil arising from destroying the family and sin in hostility towards, friends, yet how can we who clearly see the evil arising from destroying the family remain unaware of (the need of) abstaining from this sin? From the ruin of the family are totally destroyed the traditional rites and duties of the family. When rites and duties are destroyed, vice overpowers the entire family also. Krsna, when vice predominates, the women of the family become corrupt. O descendent of the Vrsnis, **when women become corrupted, it results in the intermingling of divisions**. And the intermingling in the family leads the ruiners of the family verily into hell. The forefathers of these fall down (into hell) because of being deprived of the offerings of rice-balls and water. Due to these misdeeds of the ruiners of the family, which cause intermingling of divisions, the traditional rites and duties of the castes and families become destroyed. O Janardana, we have heard that living in hell becomes inevitable for those persons whose family duties get destroyed. -- GambhirAnanda</sub>

To read more in detail, refer:
[K.S. Bhagavan's critique of Adi Shankara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9202/1049)

Comment: That the Varna System will be ruined in Kali Yuga is mentioned in many Scriptures.In fact without destroying the Varnasrama,which is the very  backbone of a virtuous society,the wholesale ingress of Sin(the paapa Purusha, who dominates in Kali Yuga) into it is not possible.So in Kali Yuga it is necessary that Varna systems aren't be followed and that the castes should be mixed or corrupted.

Comment: @iammilind--The examples you quoted suits but if you observe nowadays Brahmins are downpulling Brahmins themselves. There is no helping tendency at all among the varnas. All for commercial aspects. Money is the vital anywhere. Of course the answer is acceptable to 85%

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan That's the **greatnesss** of Kali Yuga, Brahmans work for Sudras in Kali Yuga. By Sudras, i mean people who are money minded, corrupt and all negative gunas.

Comment: @The Destroyer Well said---  that is what happening throughout.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, IMO, it's unfair to compare "Shudra"-s with "all negatives". In fact, Unlike "Vaishya"-s (money minded) the "Shudra"-s are supposed to be "serviced minded" due to natural attributes. One of the Veda-s suggests that (somewhere in this site), everyone is by default born as Shudra. Only after recollecting their natural tendency, they re-become anyone of the 3 *Varna*-s. That's why other 3 are called "Dvija" (twice born). Nothing wrong in being "money minded" (unless Brahmana). A whole passage in Mahabharata, where Yudhishtira explains, how the wealth is necessity to everyone.

Comment: Caste and varna are different.  There are so many castes. But the varna is four only. Caste comes under varna.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the *Four Castes* ,there is a *Fifth Caste*.These are the *Kayasths* .**After Shankaracharya Integrated Buddhism to Hinduism in the 9th Century AD ,the Buddhists formed the Fifth - Kayasth Caste** .As Buddhism did not accept the Caste system ,the ***Kayasths*** were permitted to retain there beliefs , and ***pursue any profession they liked and intermarry between Castes***.
 **Swami Vivekananda** beloged to the **Kayasth** Caste . ***According to him . modern Caste System should be Flexible , like that of Kayasths***