# According to guṇa-based varṇa system, can a Christian or Muslim be also a brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya, etc?

Tags: caste-system, other-religions, varna, gunas

According to proponents of guṇa-based varṇa system (i.e., those that do not believe you are born into one specific Hindu varṇa), can a Christian or Muslim be also a brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya, etc., based on the guṇas they acquired during the course of their life?

For example, can a learned man and a practicing Muslim like the former/late President of India [A. P. J. Abdul Kalam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._P._J._Abdul_Kalam) be called a brāhmaṇa?

Also, according to this system, are qualities (guṇas) that describe the 4 four varṇas are present in all individuals? I.e., can a brāhmaṇa behave like śūdra at times and vice versa?

Comment: Even plants and soil and gemstones can be classified in four categories...

Comment: Guna-based varna system is a theoretical concept so far. there is no any mean by which it can be manifested into practicality.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Plants I agree. But lifeless soil and gemstones?

Comment: Even deities and planets have been classified in four types. However one is not superior or inferior to one another.

Comment: If soils are lifeless, how plants grow on it ? :) @sv.

Comment: Of course, there were "Boston Brahmins" @sv. :-)

Comment: every country/society has intellectuals, warriors, merchants and workers. these divisions are intrinsic because they're created by bhagavan, and most people will automatically fall into one of these 4 buckets based on their predominant nature. Due to varna-sankara, these traits can also be mixed. e.g. a Suta is born to brahmin mother & kshatriya father, so his profession (charioteer) plays the mixed role of warrior and adviser. Even Asuras have these 4 varnas. But to be 'branded' a vedic term like brahmana, kshatriya, vaishya, shudra - they need to accept Vedas as authority.

Comment: "guṇa-based varṇa system" - this is a case of chicken & egg. Because one exhibits fighting tendencies in this birth, he will be born in a family of kshatriyas in the next. Because he is born in a family of kshatriyas in this birth, he has a head-start in physical & mental strength to fight enemies, and if he follows those as a duty, he helps society and achieve salvation. Krishna is saying "If you're born as a 6'6" tall, fast male in a family of athletes, try and become a basketball player, instead of being an accountant", to which people scream "OOOH BIRTH-BASED DOWN DOWN"

Comment: most people who are angry about the birth-based varna, are confused about what path to follow, because of the above mentioned varna-sankara. But there is one path that is open to all - letting go of the ego.

Comment: Whatever is being peddled as guns based caste system is incorrect. Non Hindus don't have caste system

Comment: @sv. Even Grahas have this classification. For example, Guru is Brahmana because he is preceptor and knows Supreme Brahman and all Sastras.  But unfortunately *it is said* people are applying *caste-system* for *unconscious* planets.

Comment: @Thelittlenaruto are you serious "if soil is life less how plant grow". For that matter even atoms are life less, how are you living? Soil is completely lifeless beyond any arguments or contradictions, plants only grow on them. We also eat life less food, how are we living?

Comment: @Thelittlenaruto okay then please explain how is soil having life and how do plants get their life from soil.

Comment: Obviously! A society cannot function without varna based classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > *"can a Christian or Muslim be also a brāhmaṇa, kṣatriya, etc., based on the guṇas they acquired during the course of their life?"*

**Yes**.
As already stated in Gita, the classification is decided based on the nature. It is not related to ethnicity. The 4 classes are ever existent irrespective of religions.

> BG 18.41 - O scorcher of enemies, the duties of the Brahmanas, the Ksatriyas and the Vaisyas, as also of the Sudras have been **fully classified according to the virtues born from Nature**.
>   -- Gambhirananda translation

There is no reference of whether only a certain group of people can be part of these 4 classes.

---

> > *"For example, can a learned man and a practicing Muslim like the former/late President of India A. P. J. Abdul Kalam be called a brāhmaṇa?"*

**Yes** [IMHO].
Coincidentally I have taken Dr. Kalam's reference as *Brahmana* in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8218/1049). I will categorise Albert Einstein also in the same category. See my answer in: [Who becomes a Brahmin?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24211/1049)

Abdul Kalam had all, what it takes to become Brahmana. Started from a very humbled background (*Shudra*), who used to petty jobs. He was sincere and knowledgeable in his field (*Brahmana*). Publicly he was Never behind money (*Vaishya*) or fame (*Kshatriya*). Being bachelor throughout the life, he could have been on the path of *Brahmacharya*. He had love for children and always thought well about his country.

---

> > *"the 4 four varṇas are present in all individuals?"*

**Yes**.
Like how anyone cannot escape 4 directions (north/south, east/west), every individual will fall under these 4 classes without fail.
Sometimes due to inter-class marriages, certain sub-classes of these 4 classes are created. However these sub-classes are just fine-tuning of the original 4 classes. More information here:
[What are the order & duties of the children born from intermixing/hybridisation of 4 classes?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22133/what-are-the-order-duties-of-the-children-born-from-intermixing-hybridisation)

---

> > *"can a brāhmaṇa behave like śūdra at times and vice versa?"*

**Yes**.
During lifetime, people may choose to alter their *Swa-Dharma*. e.g.

- Mahatma Gandhi was born & worked according to *Vaishya* division; However at later point of his life, he acted like a *Brahmana* [read BG 18.42]
- Drona/Ashwathama were *Brahamana*, but fought on behalf of Hastinapur as of they were *Kshatriya*s; Similarly [Krishna was born & brought up into *Vaishya* division](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19310/1049), but lived life as *Kshatriya*

Comment: 'people may choose to alter their Swa-Dharma' - this implies people are born into a particular dharma/profession? I think this svadharma concept is closed tied to birth-based varṇa. Do you believe that everyone is a born a śūdra?

Comment: @sv. I read somewhere in this site that certain Veda declares everyone as born Shudra. Shudra is service-class while other 3 classes belong to "Dvija" (second born). How I interpret this Veda verse, is that -- all don't have those inherent qualities of being "Dvija" at birth, but rather they have to earn it by studying their respective profession/work. Personally I believe that, person assumes their parent/father's *Swadharma* by default. e.g. A doctor's kid tends to be doctor & actor's son tends to be actor. -- In modern times, however quality deviations happens due to external factors.