# Can the Guna-Karma classification of the Varna system be translated into profession?

Tags: caste-system

What is the Varna of:

- an engineer
- a singer
- a doctor

I have chosen a few random samples to understand the Varna system better. How would these be classified as - Brahmin, Vaishya, Sudra and Kshatriya?

Or, is it valid to apply the Varna classification to the profession of person? Can guna-karma translate into profession?

Comment: I think [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9202/2995) answers your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [K.S. Bhagavan's critique of Adi Shankara](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9196/k-s-bhagavans-critique-of-adi-shankara)

Comment: In reality, Varna is based only on Karma and Guna. Guna is decided by Karma of previous births. Guna which dominates us alone can decide our passion for something. Jatis (Kulas or Castes) have certain innate Varna. But in this Kali Yuga, people blindly follow fad and do what they think rather what they actually are. This is causing confusion and birth based Varna is going wrong in Kali Yuga. In other Yugas, it was fine. In current age, we only should follow, Varna based on Guna.

Comment: @TheDestroyer  >Jatis (Kulas or Castes) have certain innate Varna.
Are you sure about this?

Comment: That is a totally different question: http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/558/is-this-type-of-closing-a-question-valid/560#560

Comment: It is not valid to apply Guna Karma classification to present day professions. They are different. An engineer, doctor, singer should not be equalted to Brahmin, Vaishya, Kshatriya. Because doctors are earning this by learning and with proper education.

Answer (score 4):

from my perspective, engineer-Doctor or singer can be anyone from vaidic society, as i read some books like Mahabharat(Aranya parva, shanti parva), Bhagvad Geeta, Meluha(set of books who is best to educate our vedic cast system as per my brief's).

now let's take some notes here.

```
A son of Brahmin, if he fails to complete his education, becomes a     
Shudra. Similarly, son of a Shudra or even a Dasyu, if he completes his 
education can become a Brahmin, Kshatriya or Vaishya. This is pure     
meritocracy. The way degrees are accorded today, Yajnopaveet was 
provided in Vedic system. Further, non-compliance with the code of 
conduct for each Varna could result in taking away of the Yajnopaveet.
```

for example, Parsuram, by born he was Bramhin but as per their karma can you put them in category of bramhin as they demolished  kshatriya form whole world several times..

so, what is the actual Varna system in our Vedic time?

```
In Vedic culture, everyone is considered to be born as Shudra. Then 
based on his or her education, one becomes a Brahmin, Kshatriya or 
Vaishya. This completion of education is considered to be a second 
birth. Hence these three Varnas are called “Dwija” or twice-born. But 
those who remain uneducated for whatever reasons are not discarded from 
society. They continue as Shudra and perform support-activities for the
society.
```

Another example MR. Ravan, who is by born Bramhin, a great shiv bhakt and pandit and .. and lots more but actually he is considered as RAKSHASH (forgive me lord Ravan). so in another word a varna vyavastha is also depends on what person think, what he want to be.

but for only your Question perspectives,

An engineer should be in **category of Bramahin,** why? because Lord **Vishvakarma** is bramhin.

A singer is **Vaishya,** for example Apsara's,

and a doctor is also a **bramhin** , Lord **Dhanvantri**..

The original varna system was quite flexible in which one’s varna could be changed based on one’s skill and was not fixed as is often understood.
There is no element of birth-based discrimination of any manner in the Vedas.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.

Comment: @Yogi Well, Brahmins don't have a duty to study the Brahma Sutras and attain knowledge of Brahman, they just have a duty to study the Vedas.   But it's certainly a good thing to do.

Comment: Lord Ravan!? How is he a lord? He is a Rakshas. Dhanvantari, Apsaras etc., are not humans. They are devatas and damsels. Our classifications do not apply to according to our classification. Guna nad Karma classification is not a profession.  They are different. Do not apply that classification to present day classifcation. Occupation based clasification is not applicable now a days.