# Which scripture is the source of the verse "kalau śūdra sambhavaḥ"?

Tags: scripture, caste-system, identification-request, shudra

"kalau śūdra sambhavaḥ" means all humans are Shudras in Kali Yuga. Which scriptures are the source of this verse? Is this found in Bhagavata Purana?

Comment: See this question : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17740/does-not-performing-the-garbhadana-samskara-result-in-sudra-progeny.

Comment: In this age it is very difficult to become exactly a Vedic brāhmaṇa. That's very, very difficult, because everyone has become śūdra. "Kalau śūdra-sambhavaḥ" [Skanda Purāṇa]. In the Kali-yuga you cannot find out exactly a qualified brāhmaṇa.  check this link: https://vanisource.org/wiki/740227_-_Lecture_SB_01.02.06_-_Calcutta