What if all 16 samskaras are not done is the person still considered a twice born?
The sastras mention 16 sanskaras.. But in present age not all sanskaras are performed. Then can such a person still be called a dwija?

Vivaha is the basic samskara for all. For barhmins, it is upanayana, without which they can't be considered as dvija.

Related --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17740/4732
