# Proportion of gunas in four varnas obtained by birth

Tags: scripture, varna, gunas, shudra

I read the [following lines](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=18&field_nsutra_value=41&etradi=1&choose=1) by Ramanujacharya from [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/46355/661) answer

> The nature of Brahmanas, Ksatriyas, Vaisyas, and Sudras are due to
> their respective inherent dispositions. The meaning is that their past
> Karma has been the cause of determining births as Brahmanas etc. The
> Sattva and other Gunas are the result of such Karma. **The Sattva-guna
> is born from the inherent nature of the Brahmana becoming dominant by
> suppressing the alities of Rajas and Tamas. The ality of Rajas
> originates from the inherent nature of the Ksatriyas becoming dominant
> by suppressing alities of Sattva and Tamas. Tamoguna arises from the
> inherent nature of the Vaisya, becoming dominant in a little way by
> suppressing Sattva and Rajas.** The duties and works assigned to them
> according to the Gunas constituting their inherent nature, are
> expounded and allotted by the Sastras in the order described. For the
> Sastras analyse that the Brahmanas etc., possess such and such
> attributes and such and such are their duties and occupations.

These lines clarify two points

1. Proportion of gunas in an individual, which is obtained by birth, are **result of her karmas in previous lives**.
2. Varna obtained by birth solely **depends on the proportion of gunas** obtained by the individual during birth.

I can roughly present it as below

> **Brahmana**: Sattva >> Rajas, Tamas
>
> **Ksatriya** : Rajas >> Sattva, Tamas
>
> **Vaisya** : Tamoguna > Sattva, Rajas

The proportion of gunas in Sudra is absent in those lines.

What is the proportion of gunas in a Sudra? Does *any scripture other than commentaries* contain details about all these proportions of varnas?

Comment: Ramanujacharya’s commentary itself gives it (in Sanskrit). I’m writing to explain in the same language as is given in the question. Not actual translations.: for a Shudra- Tamo becoming dominant in excess suppresses the Sattva and Tamas. For Vaishya it says Tamas is dominant in little way, for Shudra they say tamas is dominant in excess.

Comment: Sorry Tamo dominates in excess and suppresses Sattva and Rajas**

Comment: @Archit Are you good at Sanskrit?

Comment: no hardly :D. Can understand only simple verses.

Comment: hahaha...................

Comment: How does one determine the relative proportion of gunas in any individual? Not just by caste (varna)