# Sanskrit references for the usage of the word varna for a given sense

Tags: scripture, sanskrit, varna, terminology, meaning

The word **Varna** has been used by scriptures **in different senses/meanings** based on the context. This question is restricted to the usage of Varna in Humans only.

I know at least five senses:

1. Varna assigned by Krishna for each individual based on [guna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/48319/661) and karma of the individual
2. Varna assigned by astrological zodiac sign for each individual
3. Varna based on the activity of a person at a particular instant of time
4. Varna obtained from family
5. Varna saying the color of an individual

Some among these may be the same. I think that (1), (2), (3), (5) are distinct types. As per my current knowledge, I am guessing that (1), (4)  are the same. But this question is not about grouping them.

There are several other meanings for the word varna such as letter, gold, etc., which does not relate to human. So, I am neglecting such other senses for this question.

I am in search of the Sanskrit verses that use every particular sense of the word **वर्ण* or *वर्णा**. I can list Sanskrit verses for (1), (4), and (5) but not known for (2) and (3).

1. **Varna assigned by Krishna for each individual  based on guna and karma of the individual**

> चातु**र्वर्ण्यं** मया सृष्टं गुणकर्मविभागशः।
>
> तस्य कर्तारमपि मां विद्ध्यकर्तारमव्ययम्।।
>
> [[Verse 13, Chapter 4, Bhagavad Gita, The Mahabharata]](https://www.yugalsarkar.com/bhagwad-gita-chapter-4-shlok-13-sanskrit-translation)

We can also find the name वर्णाश्रमविधायिनि in this sense of the word Varna in Lalita sahastranaamavali.

2. **Varna assigned by astrological zodiac sign for each individual**

I don't have an authentic Sanskrit verse here. I have information available in English from secondary references only. The [information is](http://mokshaastrology.blogspot.com/2009/04/varna-refers-to-caste.html)

> BRAHMIN VARNA: Person whose Birth Rashi is Cancer or Scorpio or Pisces is considered Brahmin by Varna in Hindu Vedic Astrology .
>
> KSHATRIYA VARNA: Person whose Birth Rashi is Aries or Leo or Sagittarius is considered Kshatriya by Varna in Hindu Vedic Astrology.
>
> VAISHYA VARNA: Person whose Birth Rashi is Taurus or Virgo or Capricorn is considered Vaishya by Varna in Hindu Vedic Astrology.
>
> SHUDRA VARNA: Person whose Birth Rashi is Gemini or Libra or Aquarius is considered Shudra by Varna in Hindu Vedic Astrology.

3. **Varna based on the activity of the person at a particular instant of time**

> In this sense of varna, varna is assigned to a person based on the task
> she is performing at a particular point in time. If the person thinks
> or reads about anything she is a Brahmana at that time. If she
> administers her life then she is Kshatriya. If she manages trading or
> other trading related activities then she is vaishya. If she performs
> any other task in her life then she is a shudra. So, varna in this
> case does not depend on the individual and only depends on the task
> the person is doing at that point in time. In general, a person
> becomes brahmana, Kshatriya, vaishya, and sudra in a single day.

I heard it from preaching and I don't have any reference in any language.

4. **Varna obtained from family**

I am confused about this. I can see several references such as Rama being Kshetriya since he was born to Kshatriyas and a lot of verses are there that say that Varna is obtained from biological parents. I think that it is the same as (1).

> विप्रस्य त्रिषु **वर्णे**षु नृपतेर्वर्णयोर्द्वयोः ।
>
> वैश्यस्य **वर्णे** चैकस्मिन् षडेतेऽपसदाः स्मृताः ||
>
> [[10, 10, Manu Smrithi]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201743.html)

5. **Varna saying the color of an individual**

In this sense, varna just stands for the color of the individual, there are lots of references to the usage of the word varna in this sense. I am listing some names from [Lalitha sahastranaamavali](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/lalita1000.html).

> पीतवर्णा, शुक्लवर्णा, आरक्तवर्णा, रक्तवर्णा

---

**Where can I find Sanskrit verses that use the word Varna in the senses of (2) and (3)?**

Comment: (3) is a modern day interpretation. There’s nothing like that. It’s like saying when kings did Yajnas they became Brahmins while doing Yajnas. Or if a Brahmin washes his or her own clothes then they’re Shudras.

Comment: (4) is not same as (1) , refer to https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/7/11/35/ this

Comment: Varna from family and of actions are supposed to be the same thing. As in you inherit the behavior traits that define a varna from your parents.