# Are there any possible senses(meanings) for the word Varna wrt humans other than the ones given?

Tags: scripture, sanskrit, varna, meaning, interpretation

I recently [asked a question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48376/sanskrit-references-for-the-usage-of-the-word-varna-for-a-given-sense) requesting Sanskrit verses containing the word Varna in different contexts.

I provided the five senses:

1. Varna assigned by Krishna for each individual based on guna and karma of the individual
2. Varna assigned by astrological zodiac sign for each individual
3. Varna based on the activity of a person at a particular instant of time
4. Varna obtained from family
5. Varna says the color of an individual

Some of the senses mentioned may be the same and others are distinct. Some senses may be due to the modern interpretations as mentioned [in this comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48376/sanskrit-references-for-the-usage-of-the-word-varna-for-a-given-sense#comment151642_48376), which I am not sure about.

Are there any senses for Varna, in scriptures, (wrt humans) other than those mentioned above? The sense you are providing for the word Varna should be backed up by a Sanskrit verse containing वर्ण or वर्णा in it.