# What Varna and caste would work of today's physicians and doctors be classified as according to duty of various varnas?

Tags: caste-system

In the respective Varna what position they would be? Kindly tell me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Guna-Karma classification of the Varna system be translated into profession?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12320/can-the-guna-karma-classification-of-the-varna-system-be-translated-into-profess)

Comment: If "Doctors" do service to the society (free or non profit) then due to high intellectual level, they can be classified as *Brahmana*. If they practice it as a profession for earning money, then they become *Vaishya*. In case, if they don't deserve "Doctor"-ship, yet still they practice it either as a profession or as a service, then they are *Shudra*.

Comment: This is certainly not an opinion based question. The answer is-  from occupation varna can't be determined.

Comment: classified under brahmins

Comment: varna does not change based on occupation. Let's say someone practised to be a doctor for 2 years then became an IPS officer? He doesn't go from being a brahmin or something else to a kshatriya in this life itself. What happens when he gives up that job after 10 years and takes up 2-3 occupations such as farming plus teaching? Then what should his caste be? The premise of the Q is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

One can not decide like that. One can not say that since you are such and such by occupation you belong to such and such varna.

What the scriptures will tell us is simply what the recommended occupations are for a person belonging to a particular varna.

For example, for the Vaishya varna the following are the recommended jobs:

> 63. To invest money on interest, to be a jeweller, to tend cattle, tillage and trade, — these are declared as occupations for the Vaisya
>       caste,
>
> **ParAsara Smriti 1-63**

But, that does not mean  one can also say that all persons in trading business are Vaishya by varna.

Similarly with doctors. Just like a Vaishya can be a doctor, even a Brahmin can be one too. But its a different thing that then he will be considered as degraded.

> **The four [classes of] Vipras**, who sell sheep, who are painters, **who
>   are physicians,** and who read the positions of stars, should never be
>   adored, even if they are equal to Vrihaspati in learning. (378)
>
> **Atri Smriti's Chapter 1.**

This above verse clearly shows that people belonging to different occupations can belong to one particular varna (Brahmin here). So, ascertaining varna from occupation is not possible.