# English translation of Bharata Paryatanam by Kuttikrishna Marar?

Tags: mahabharata, translation-request

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuttikrishna_Marar):

> [**Bharata Paryatanam**](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13356486-bharatha-paryatanam) (Travel through Bharata), another important work of **Kuttikrishna Marar** is a critical exposition of the characters and main events in the epic Mahabharata. Bharata Paryatanam shows his immense knowledge of the epic, Mahabharata.

Has this been translated to English? If yes, where can I find the translation?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on-topic for the site, as it's asking for an English translation not for some Hindu scripture, but just a random scholarly book on the Mahabharata.  But in any case, as far as I can tell Bharata Paryatanam (also spelled Bharathaparyadanam) has never been translated into English.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I believe this is on-topic in the same way someone's looking for English translation of Shankaracharya's commentary on Vishnu Sahasranamam.

Comment: Well, I see a big difference between asking for a translation of the work of an Acharya, given that such a work would be revered by some sect of Hinduism or the other, compared to asking for a translation of a random scholarly work which isn't treated as sacred by anyone.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I agree there is a difference. But what I'm trying to say is just because someone considers a work by an acharya or regular scholar sacred or not should not prevent a user on this forum from asking a question as long as it's connected to Hinduism in some way. When we have entertained a question such as this: [K.S. Bhagavan's critique of Adi Shankara](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9196/2995), we should also entertain translation requests of works of critics.

Comment: @keshav i think this is on topic as book is about Mahabharata. If only works of acharyas are allowed, then we also must not allow translations of western scholars on Vedas.

Comment: @sv. Well, I think we should only entertain translation requests of works that someone or the other considers sacred (not necessarily the person posting the question).  But it's fine to ask other sorts of questions about scholarly works on Hinduism.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Well, Western translations of the Vedas are different, because they're still a translation of a Hindu scripture.  I just think that we shouldn't allow translation requests for works other than scriptures or the works of Acharyas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I don't see any harm in allowing such questions. Both answers to [K.S. Bhagavan's critique of Adi Shankara](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9196/2995) are based on random articles on the web without actually reading the critic's work in any form. If a tr. request of K.S. Bhagavan's work is allowed here, someone someday can post a better, more conclusive answer.