# How is birth time rectification done in astrology?

Tags: astrology

In astrology, there is the concept of ["birth time rectification (BTR)"](http://kpastrologeronline.com/birth-time-rectification-correction-rectify-birthtime).

As that website says (the site seems to be copy-protected), in natal astrology, knowing the time of birth (TOB) is vital for the predictions to be correct. But most natives are unsure of the exact TOBs for whatever reasons.

So, the astrologer corrects the TOB by using some methods. What I find strange here is that in the calculations, the astrologer uses the TOB that the native provides him with (which is inaccurate).

So my questions are how the astrologer does the BTR using the TOB of the native, which according the astrologer, is inaccurate? What methods are used here?

How can the astrologer come up with the correct TOB by using a chart which is cast using an incorrect/approximate TOB?

Comment: If the TOB is wrong, the chart is also wrong. in those cases, some astrologers use the chart of first born son. Closely related [Hindu astrology and the timing of birth](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18046/5212).

Comment: BTR as introduced by KP Astrology is a hoax

Comment: So try to post an answer on those lines. @RakeshJoshi

Comment: other than Time of Birth, there are other indications as to what nakshtra or rasi a person was born under. for e.g. if according to hospital TOB, child is calculated as shravana nakshatra 4-padam, but as child grows up, it exhibits tendencies that are more common for dhanishta nakshatra (1-padam), then it's possible that the recorded time was bit earlier than actual birth time. shravana is deva-gana, dhanista is rakshasa-gana. similarly, other factors, like foreign travel, or accidents are characteristic of certain rasi/lagna/times.if actual life scenarios don't match TOB, then BTR can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways for birth time rectification. Here, can use these 2 ways -

1) In one's birth chart, 9th house indicates parents and their ruling planets. 
So, find out father/mother ruling planets and check whether the 9th house of the native's birth chart is showing their ruling planets or not.

Here, Ruling planets means Moon's star(nakshatra) lord, ascendant lord, ascendant star lord of D1 chart of parents.

2) Similarly, in a child's birth chart, ascendant lord of D12 must be connected to 9th house of D1.

If they don't match, then adjust the time, and check again.

Comment: Ok but if the birth time of the child is wrong then 9th house may change lordship? Then?

Comment: @Rickross, they don't rely on the 'possibly wrong' data to correct the same data - obviously that cannot be done. maybe they rely on external factors - if you see that website you linked, he asks for 20 different important events that happened in the person's life.

Comment: @Rickross,  first we have to check with given time. If it is wrong, then, automatically, the 9th house in child's chart does not match with parent's ruling planets.  Next, can slightly move the time and again prepare the whole chart with all 12 houses, and then try to match the 9th house with parent's RP. If they match, then can use 2nd rule to confirm this time.