# Jaimini's view on Krishna

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, jaimini

I was reading this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14022/why-did-vedvyasa-mention-his-shishya-jaminis-opinion-saying-in-brahma-sutra/14035#14035), where the author of the answer Keshav Srinivasan speculated that Rishi Jaimini was totally in agreement with Vedanta School, but was pretending to have views like that of Purva Mimansa School.

If that is true then as we know from [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a047.htm) that Rishi Jaimini was present during the time of Mahabharata war on the battlefield of Kurukshetra surrounding Shri Bhishma on the bed of arrows.

> Vaisampayana said, 'Listen, O king, with pure heart and concentrated attention, as to how, O tiger among the Kurus, the high-souled Bhishma cast off his body. As soon as the Sun, passing the solstitial point, entered in his northerly course, Bhishma, with concentrated attention, caused his soul (as connected with and independent of the body) to enter his soul (in its independent and absolute state). Surrounded by many foremost of Brahmanas, that hero, his body pierced with innumerable arrows, blazed forth in great beauty like Surya himself with his innumerable rays. Surrounded by Vyasa conversant with the Vedas by the celestial Rishi Narada, by Devasthana, by Asmaka Sumantu, **by Jaimini**, by the high-souled Paila, by Sandilya, by Devarata, by Maitreya of great intelligence, by Asita and Vasishtha and the high-souled Kausika, by Harita and Lomasa and Atri's son of great intelligence, by Vrihaspati and Sukra and the great sage Chyavana, by Sanatkumara and Kapila and Valmiki and Tumvuru and Kuru, by Maudgalya and Rama of Bhrigu's race, and the great sage Trinavindu, by Pippalada and Vayu and Samvarta and Pulaha and Katha, by Kasyapa and Pulastya and Kratu and Daksha and Parasara, by Marichi and Angiras and Kasmya and Gautama and the sage Galava, by Dhaumya and Vibhanda and Mandavya and Dhaumra and Krishnanubhautika, by Uluka, that foremost of Brahmanas and the great sage Markandeya, by Bhaskari and Purana and Krishna and Suta,--that foremost of virtuous persons, surrounded by these and many other highly-blessed sages of great souls and possessed of faith and self-restraint and tranquillity of mind, the Kuru hero looked like the Moon in the midst of the planets and the stars. Stretched on his bed of arrows, that tiger among men, Bhishma, with pure heart and joined palms, thought of Krishna in mind, word, and act.

Then it is obvious that he knew about Krishna and he had seen Krishna, so what were his views on Krishna? Did Rishi Jaimini had knowledge that Krishna is an incarnation of Shriman Narayana and that he is Brahman?

A point to be noted, according to Rishi Jaimini and Purva Mimansa thinks Brahman is not the material, substantial cause of Universe rather Brahman is a powerful eternal being.

After reading [this](http://%5Chttps://doc-0s-bc-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/tmum2cv8glv4g5nsml0r53khvhd08sgq/1479232800000/02058467015715614041/*/1P8PBgagKhv0R7qq4VidvEYhqKnoHEO7iQStXIyF6IW3ItJNjJvWfsPCqsDH9Xjf043F0XPqOit9_vOxt) from Skanda Purana it appears that according to Rishi Jaimini Shriman Narayana is all powerful and omnipotent aka Brahman.

Answer (score 7):

In the Padma Purana (6.236.12), Sri Rudra addresses Sri Parvathi on why many Tamasa texts (i interpret as texts that aren't fully true, has ignorance in the opinion it provides) were created. Among the many texts, Sri Rudra says

> "madAjnayA **jaimininA** pUrvavedamapArthakaM
>
> nirIshvareNa vAdena kRtaMshAstramahattaraM" (Padma Pu 6.236.12)

This means

> Sri Rudra Says - It is by my command that the false purva veda (purva
>   mimamsa) was created by Jaimini, a great shastra that is filled with
>   arguments which discounts (the role of) Ishwara (Brahman).

It discounts the role of Ishwara as the material AND efficient cause of the world, something which purva mimamsa does not recognize. This was identified and refuted by Vyasa who does acknowledge Jaimini (and his works) and only refutes those ideologies which were wrong (purva mimamsa, for that matter all the darshanas are NOT  entirely wrong, only certain portions of them).

Thanks to @keshavSrinivasan for this info - Vedanta Desikan's (a Sri Vaishnavite Acharya) Seshvara Mimamsa is an interesting commentary on the Purva Mimamsa Sutras. It's purpose is basically to answer the question "What parts of Purva Mimamsa can be accepted by a member of the Vedanta school?!"

The actual Sanskrit text can be found in the image below (refer line 3 & 4 from the top)

[image]

This is taken from page [page 937 of the Uttara Khanda of Padma Purana](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/puranas/padma_purana_6uttara.pdf)

You may find other parts of the Padma purana and others too in their native Sanskrit form [here](http://vedicreserve.mum.edu/puran.htm).

A reading of Chapter 235 and 236 sheds a lot more light of the context of why Sri Rudra did this and what others are classified as Tamasic texts (whose ideologies are strongly refuted by the Brahma Sutra of Badarayana).

Conclusion - Jaimini was aware of the knowledge of Brahman, and that Krishna is Brahman but pretended to not know it (or rather not showcase it in his purva mimamsa sutras) as instructed by Rudra. His knowledge of the same comes from your citation that he was a witness of the Bhishma Yudhistira Samvada.

Comment: You may also refer to information in Keshav's answer (the same link you mentioned in your question) for more contextual information on the same.

Comment: The same logic applies to Darshana texts made by Kapila Rishi (Samkhya) and Gautama Rishi (Nyaya) who were also attendees of the discussion between Bhishma and the Pandavas (in the presence of Bhagavan). This is again tackled in Padma Purana, 6.236.1-5.