# Does bhagwatam clearly say that krishna is the bhagwan or is there any other meaning behind behind such statement?

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana

Most of the iskconites usually say bhagwatam 1.3.28

एते चांशकला: पुंस: कृष्णस्तु भगवान् स्वयम् ।
इन्द्रारिव्याकुलं लोकं मृडयन्ति युगे युगे ॥

To show that golok niwasi shri krishna is the only bhagwan not any one else.

I would like to know, if there is something to know or this is it?

Comment: 1.3.28: *But Lord Kṛṣṇa is the Supreme Beiṇg himself and all these, parts and smaller parts (incarnations or aṁśas) of the Supreme Being who give happiness to the world (when it is) troubled by the enemies of Indra (i.e. demons) in every epoch.*

He is shown to be Bhagavāna and Supreme Godhead here. Kramasandarbha explains the difference between Bhagavān and his parts as follows: The Supreme Lord, by His divine will, can manifest His power any­where without interruption, while the parts (aṃśas) or incarnations can manifest these for performing their appointed mission.

Comment: Though Kṛṣṇa is included in the list of incarnations, He is not merely a part (aṃśa) of the Supreme Being but the Supreme Being Himself. I guess that makes the meaning pretty clear enough.

Comment: Why did bhagwatam mentions shri Ram as param ? Also in bhagwatam, shri ram is said as bhagwantam adipurusham?

Comment: That's not the original question you asked. As for that, you have to cite the verse no. where the Bhāgavata Purāṇa states so, the one you stated 1.3.28 is only about Kr̥ṣṇa being the Supreme being,  it doesn't specify Rāma.

Answer (score 1):

**श्रीरामचन्द्र चरणौ शरणं प्रपद्ये।**

Salutations to the feet of Bhagwan Shri Ramchandra.

Krishnastu bhagwan swaym also means shri Ram is the bhagwan as

(**यो रामः कृष्णतामेत्य सार्वात्म्यं प्राप्य लीलया .
अतोषयद्देव्मौनिपटलं तं नतोऽस्म्यहम् १**

That RAma, who having transformed himself as Krishna, attained Sarvaatmaktaa* by his very lila (divine exploits, pastimes); and thus deities-sages-masses were completely satisfied on this earth . I make prostration before that same Śrī Rāma.....
Krishna upanishad

1.3.28
**एते चांशकला: पुंस: कृष्णस्तु भगवान् स्वयम् ।
इन्द्रारिव्याकुलं लोकं मृडयन्ति युगे युगे ॥**

All of the above-mentioned incarnations are either plenary portions or portions of the plenary portions of the Lord, but Lord Śrī Kṛṣṇa is the original Personality of Godhead. All of them appear on planets whenever there is a disturbance created by the atheists. The Lord incarnates to protect the theists.

Krishna upanishad clearly shows who is the bhagwan who took avtar as krishna.

**कृषिर्भुवाचकःशब्दो णश्च निवृत्तिवाचकः।
विष्णुस्तद्भावयोगच्च कृष्णों भवति शाश्वतः।‌।**

(महाभारत)

The word 'krs' means existence, 'na' means bliss. Shri Vishnu (narayan) has both of these expressions, therefore he is always called as krishna.

And hence shriman narayan is also hailed here as supreme personality of godhead. This is again confirmed by bhagwatam 1.3.5

ŚB 1.3.5
**एतन्नानावताराणां निधानं बीजमव्ययम् ।
यस्यांशांशेन सृज्यन्ते देवतिर्यङ्‍नरादय: ॥**

भगवान् का यही पुरुष जिसे नारायण कहते हैं, अनेक अवतार का अक्षय कोष है—इसी से सारेअवतार प्रकट होते हैं। इस रुप के छोटे-से- छोटे अंश से देवता, पशु-पक्षी और मनुष्य आदि योनियों का  सृष्टि होती है

This Purusha of the Lord, who is called Narayana, is the inexhaustible storehouse of many incarnations - from this all the incarnations appear. Gods, animals, birds and human beings etc. are created from the smallest part of this form.

**श्रीमद्वाराहोपनिषद्   वेद्याखण्ड सुखाकृति ।
त्रिपान्  नारायणाख्यं तद्  रामचन्द्रपदं भजे ॥**

वराह  उपनिषद एक सुखद रूप के रूप में वेदों का एक टुकड़ा है। मैं उस त्रिगुण रूप  श्री रामचंद्र के चरण कमलों में पूजा करता हूं जिसको नारायण के नाम से जाना जाता है।

The Varaha Upanishad is a fragment of the Vedas in a pleasant form. I worship at the lotus feet of that triple form of Sri Ramachandra who is known as Narayana.

Varah upanishad mangalacharan shlok shows who shri Ram who is hailed as narayan in v
ŚB 1.3.22

**नरदेवत्वमापन्न: सुरकार्यचिकीर्षया ।
समुद्रनिग्रहादीनि चक्रे वीर्याण्यत: परम् ॥ २२ ॥**

In the eighteenth incarnation, the Lord appeared as King Rāma. In order to perform some pleasing work for the demigods, He exhibited superhuman powers by controlling the Indian Ocean and then killing the atheist King Rāvaṇa, who was on the other side of the sea. Therefore , it's supreme.

So krishnastu bhagwan swaym not only refers to krishna but also to shri Ram.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is about Puranas but it's stating a issue which is larger in scale. The sentence.:

> ***"To show that golok niwasi shri krishna is the only bhagwan not any one else."***

So, my views are as follows.:

“Bhagawan” is not an ordinary designation. As ISKCON Acharyas have translated the word **“Bhagawan”** as **“Supreme Personality of Godhead”**, which in simple language is nothing but the **“Supreme Lord”** above whom there is no one.

This attribute belongs only to Bhagawan Rudra because he is the Purusha, he is the Parabrahman as per Vedas.

> *“purusho vai rudrah |” (Taittiriya Aranyaka 10:24:1).*
>
> *“Lord Rudra is the Purusha of Vedas”.*

Shruti clearly calls Rudra as the bhagwan (boss) of all devas (gods), who created all gods and gave them their respective powers, positions and designations. Shruti denies the existence of any other bhagwan (boss) who controls Rudra who is the Veda Purusha himself.

Atharvasiras Upanishad clearly states that Lord Shiva is supreme. It says that nothing in past neither was ever greater than him nor can ever be in future.

> *“yasminnida.n sarvamotaprota.n tasmAdanyanna para.n ki~nchanAsti |
> na tasmAtpUrva.n na para.n tadasti na bhUta.n nota bhavya.n yadAsIt.h |” (Atharvasiras Upanishad 5:05).*
>
> *“There is none greater than him, on whom all the worlds are strung like beads. Over ages, nothing so far in the past was ever greater than him and nothing is going to be greater than him in future”.*

Svetaswatara Upanishad also voices similar thoughts as shown below.

> *“na tasya kaarya.n karaNa.n cha vidyate na tatsamashchaabhyadhikashcha dR^ishyate |
> paraasya shaktirvividhaiva shruuyate svaabhaavikii GYaanabalakriyaa cha |” (Svetaswatara Upanishad 6:08).*
>
> *“There is no effect and no cause known of him, no one is seen like unto him or better; his high power is revealed as manifold, as inherent, acting as force and knowledge”.*

> *“na tasya kashchit.h patirasti loke na cheshitaa naiva cha tasya liN^gam.h |
> sa kaaraNa.n karaNaadhipaadhipo na chaasya kashchijjanitaa na chaadhipaH |”(Svetaswatara Upanishad 6:09).*
>
> *“There is no master of his in the world, no ruler of his, not even a sign of him. He is the cause, the lord of the lords of the organs, and there is of him neither parent nor lord”.*

So, it’s clear from above verses that there is nothing superior to Lord Rudra. He is the Supreme personality of Godhead. Now we’ll see in below verse that it is lord Rudra alone who created all Gods and blessed them with their positions and designations.

> *“yo devaanaaM prabhavashchodbhavashcha vishvaadhipo rudro maharshhiH |
> hiraNyagarbha.n janayaamaasa puurva.n sa no buddhyaa shubhayaa sa.nyunaktu” (Sve Upa. 3:4).*
>
> *“He, the omniscient Rudra, the creator of the gods and the bestower of their powers, the support of the universe, He who, in the beginning, gave birth to Hiranyagarbha—may He endow us with clear intellect!”*

> *“sa hi kṣayeṇa kṣamyasya janmanaḥ sāmrājyena divyasya cetati |
> avannavantīrupa no duraścarānamīvo rudra jāsu no bhava ||” (Rig Veda 7:46:2).*
>
> *“He (Rudra) through his lordship rules on beings of the earth, on heavenly beings (gods) through his high imperial sway (controlling influence or power). Come willingly to our doors that gladly welcome thee, and heal all sickness, Rudra. in our families”.*

Well, an interesting FACT related to the word “Bhagawan” is that Vedas hailed ONLY Lord Shiva with the title -“Bhagawan”.Yes, Vedas have not used the title called “Bhagawan” for any other god including Lord Vishnu, Lord Brahma and not even for Lord IND a also. They have used that designation exclusively only for Lord Rudra. Sri Rudram hymn from Yajurveda begins with the salutations to Rudra as the Bhagawan of Vedas. It says, ***“Om namo bhagawate rudraya |”,*** which means, ***“Salutations to lord Rudra who is the Bhagawan (Supreme personality of godhead)”.*** All other gods who received title as ‘Bhagawan’ received that title from Puranas not from Vedas. In fact in later texts (puranas), even Narada, Vyasa also got referred with that title, hence it became very colloquially used title for everyone in later texts. Bhagawan Vishnu’s names as ‘Om namo bhagawate Vasudevaya’ etc mantras are all Pouranic and not Vedic. In Vedas only Lord Rudra (Shiva) is the Bhagawan.

Not only this; in fact Rudram hymn has used the words **“Bhagawate”**, **“Bhagavo”** etc at many places addressing Rudra. Even Upanishads have greeted Rudra with this exhalted title.

> *“yo vai rudraH sa **bhagavAn**yachcha tejastasmai vai namonamaH |” (Atharvasiras Upanishad 2:19).*
>
> *“He who is Rudra, **he alone is Supreme god (Bhagawan).** He is the Supreme Light and we salute him again and again”.*

> “tasyottarataH shiro dakShiNataH pAdau ya uttarataH sa o~NkAraH ya o~NkAraH sa praNavaH yaH | praNavaH sa sarvavyApI yaH sarvavyApI so.anantaH | yo.anantastattAra.n yattAra.n tatsUkShma.n tachChukla.n | yachChukla.n tadvaidyuta.n yadvaidyuta.n tatparaM brahma yatparaM | brahma sa ekaH ya ekaH sa rudraH ya rudraH yo rudraH sa IshAnaH ya | **IshAnaH sa bhagavAn.h maheshvaraH** |” (Atharvasiras Upanishad 3:6).
>
> “The head of “the sound of Om” is on your left side. Its feet are on your right side. That “Sound of Om” is the Pranava (primeval sound). That Pranava is spread everywhere. That which is everywhere is the greatest. That which is limitless, shines like a white star. That which is also called Shuklam (seminal fluid- the basic unit of life) is very very minute. That which is minute is like a lightning power. That which is like lightning power is the ultimate Brahman (parabrahman). **That Brahman is one and only one. That one and only one is Rudra, it is also called Eeshana, it is also the ultimate God (BHAGAWAN) and it is also the lord of all things”.**

"Bhagawan" comes 35 times in Atharvashiras Upanishad, 2 times in Shvetashvatara Upanishad and 8 times in Sri Rudram hyms from Yajur Veda. So, in total 45 times in the Vedas and Vedantas (Upanishads) viz Shrutis, "Bhagawan" comes only for Bhagawan Rudra Shiva only and no one else. If anyone is counting Smritis as the 5th Veda then it's ok. It's common in there.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 0):

LORD KRISHNA SAYS EVERYONE HAS DIVINITY INSIDE. HOWEVER, AVATAR HAS DIVINITY RIGHT FROM BIRTH. THE NON-AVATAR PEOPLE NEED TO GET **BRAHM SWAROOP** after one imbibes **BRAHM NAAD** & **BRAHM PRAKASH**.THUS IN SECOND LAST STANZA OF GITA CHAPTER18; LORD KRISHNA SAYS HEY ARJUNA NOW WE BOTH RESIDE WITH **HARI SWAROOP** THAT IS THE **ULTIMATE WIN.**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/37203)