# Quotes to prove similarity between Vedic Samhita and Upanishaic Vedantic Philosophy?

Tags: vedas, vedanta

Is Vedanta the conclusion of Vedic Samhitas? Can we proove Vedantic Philosophy from Vedic Samhitas, Brahmanas and Araynakas??

Comment: You can have a general look at [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14035/20129)

Comment: Your question is a fallacy known as begging the question. The Vedanta philosophy is part of the vedic samhitas, brahmanas, and aranyakas.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Please proove that Samhitas and Brahmanas speak of Vedanta philosophy

Answer (score 1):

Ishopanishad is in the samhita portion of its shakha (it is the 40th adhyaya of Vajasaneyi Samhita of Shuklayajurveda).

The Maitrayani Upanishad belongs to Maitrayani Samhita of the Krishna Yajurveda. It talks exclusively on the superiority of the Brahman.

Thus some upanishads are itself part of the Samhita.

Further, please see the [following link](https://goldenreed-hiranyayavetasa.blogspot.com/2020/10/concordance-of-rg-veda-samhita-with.html). The link also provides a detailed comparison of the sentences in the samhitas and upanishads indicating that the philosophy behind both of them are exactly are the same.

> Hindu tradition considers the Veda Samhitās and Upaniṣads as forming
> integral parts of a single canon of orthodox scripture, the Veda.
> There must have been a really good reason for this. The reason is that
> the Veda is thoroughly consistent in its subject matter and
> fundamental metaphysics and philosophy, beginning with the Samhitās
> all the way through to the Upaniṣads.

Comment: BTW that blog is HSE user [Ram Abloh's](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/20829/ramabloh)

Comment: I have read his blog sir. I wanted more. Please present yours-Not others blog

Comment: Sorry I was unaware. I can delete my reply or include my own quotes on how certain samhitas/aranyakas are similar to upanishads in content. I just quoted the blog because it was very impressive and exhaustive.

Comment: @GIRIBLR I have already read it sir! Please do quote yours. No problem sir!