# What exactly is meant by Harernamaiva Kevalam

Tags: vishnu, shloka, chaitanya, sandhyavandanam

> हरेर्नाम हरेर्नाम हरेर्नामैव केवलम्।
>   कलौ नास्त्येव नास्त्येव नास्त्येव गतिरन्यथा॥
>
> meaning Harinama, Harinama, only Harinama ....there is no other way, no other way in the kaliyuga [for illumination].

The above sloka was mentioned by Lord Chaitanyadeva Himself. Does this sloka make sandhyavandana and all other pujas redundant and futile in this kali yuga? I am asking because its a quote from Vrihan-Naradiya-Purana and the words of Smriti are above the Puranas as per our sanatana dharma norms.

Comment: its a quote from Purana. Which Purana?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Narada Muni was repeating to many other similar verses found in other Mahapuranas i.e., Vishnu Purana and Bhagavatam in different matters.

The mode of worship change from time to time and yuga to yuga due to change in conditions and the ability of the worshippers. The spiritual levels of people has also fallen. We do not have much time to perform penances or do meditation. We even have problems in understanding the esoteric meaning of the Vedas and other holy scriptures. If much time is put in that, when do we apply those teachings and strive for moksha? Hence, the provision was made. This is the easiest way.

Vyasa says the following in Amsha 6 adhyaya 2 of Vishnu Purana

> The fruit of penance, of continence, of silent prayer, and the like, practised in the Krita age for ten years, in the Treta for one year, in the Dwápara for a month, is obtained in the Kali age in a day and night: therefore did I exclaim "Excellent, excellent, is the Kali age!" **That reward which a man obtains in the Krita by abstract meditation, in the Treta by sacrifice, in the Dwápara by adoration, he receives in the Kali by merely reciting the name of Keshava**.
>
> kaliṁ sabhājayanty āryā guṇa jñāḥ sāra-bhāginaḥ
>   yatra saṅkīrtanenaiva sarva-svārtho ’bhilabhyate  (Srimad Bhagavatam Skandha 11 chapter 5 shloka 36)
>
> Those who are actually advanced in knowledge are able to appreciate the essential value of this Age of Kali. Such enlightened persons worship Kali-yuga because in this fallen age all perfection of life can easily be achieved by the performance of saṅkīrtana.

There is also a statement in the Uttara Khanda of Ramayana where the advisors of Sri Rama says the characteristics of Yuga change and the worshipping methods also change. Hence the spiritual level of all the Varnas will be the same i.e., a Brahmana will be the same as Shudra (I have to find exact verse though).

More instances were added in an answer written by Keshav Srinivasan [Do methods of worship change according to yugas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2150/5212)

Chaitanya Mahaprabhu emphasized on Sankirtana out of nava vidha bhaktis. Hence he said that Hari Nama sankirtana is enough for getting liberation.

Adi Shankaracharya also says in his Bhaja Govindam stotra :

> bhajagovindaM bhajagovindaM
>   govindaM bhajamuuDhamate .
>   saMpraapte sannihite kaale
>   nahi nahi rakshati DukRiJNkaraNe
>
> **Worship Govinda, Worship Govinda, Worship Govinda. Oh fool! Rules of Grammar will not save you at the time of your death**.
>
> bhagavad.h giitaa kiJNchidadhiitaa
>   gaNgaa jalalava kaNikaapiitaa .
>   sakRidapi yena muraari samarchaa
>   kriyate tasya yamena na charchaa
>
> Let a man read but a little from Gitaa, drink just a drop of water from the ganges, **worship murari (govinda) just once**. He then will have no altercation with Yama. Stanza attributed to dR^iDhabhakta.

In the above verse, Adi Shankaracharya recommends worship of Krishna just even once and says the person will have no altercation with Yama which means he will not have to visit Naraka (meaning Lord will take care and give better lokas).

So, the verse strongly suggests  the nama sankirtana of Lord Vishnu. That doesn't mean we should leave our duties of performing Sandhyavandanam and deeds like visiting temples. Lord Krishna states one should do his own duty. The verse is suggesting that Lord Vishnu's name is enough for liberation.

Comment: if it is enough, why would someone take extra strain?

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee That is them to decide. It is based on belief and level of people. They can chose the way which suits them personally. Lord has given that freedom too.

Comment: On one side, i get that one who is devoid of sandhya becomes sudra and reborn as dog.On another side I get that doing any other spiritual activity with nama is namaparadh. naam is supreme.The concept of namaparadh is strict indeed and its almost impossible for a common man to do naam without namaaparaadh.

Answer (score 2):

No , not at all. Shree Krishna himself mentioned in Srimad Bhagavatam while advising Uddhava that. One can worship him  in three ways.

Uddhava a great devotee of Shree Krishna once asked him to explain about  the prescribed [**method of worshiping**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/27/2/) him in his Deity form and also said that the great sages like Narada , Vyasa and his own spiritual master, Bṛhaspati  repeatedly declare that such worship brings the greatest benefit possible in human life. This whole chapter is about Puja Vidhi of Bhagavanta

Upon the enquiry Shree Krishna said.

> वैदिकस्तान्त्रिको मिश्र इति मे त्रिविधो मखः
>  त्रयाणामीप्सितेनैव
>   विधिना मां समर्चरेत् ॥ [**11.27.7**](https://archive.org/details/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/page/n2111) ॥
>
> vaidikas tāntriko miśra iti me tri-vidho makhaḥ
>  trayāṇām
>   īpsitenaiva vidhinā māṁ samarcaret
>
> My worship is threefold Vedic ,Tantric and synthesis of these two .
>   But of these three modes one should offer me worship according to
>   method of his choice and suitability.

Further he said that

> पद्ममष्टदलं तत्र कर्णिकाकेसरोज्ज्वलम्
>  उभाभ्यां वेदतन्त्राभ्यां
>   मह्यं तूभयसिद्धये ॥ [**11.27.26**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/27/25-26/)॥
>
> padmam aṣṭa-dalaṁ tatra karṇikā-kesarojjvalam
>  ubhābhyāṁ
>   veda-tantrābhyāṁ mahyaṁ tūbhaya-siddhaye
>
> Then, following the regulations of both the Vedas and the tantras, he
>   should offer Me water for washing the feet, water for washing the
>   mouth, arghya and other items of worship. **By this process he
>   achieves both material enjoyment and liberation.**
>
> ---
>
> एवं क्रियायोगपथैः पुमान्वैदिकतान्त्रिकैः|
>  अर्चन्नुभयतः सिद्धिं मत्तो
>   विन्दत्यभीप्सिताम् ॥ [**11.27.49**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/27/49/) ॥
>
> evaṁ kriyā-yoga-pathaiḥ pumān vaidika-tāntrikaiḥ
>  arcann ubhayataḥ
>   siddhiṁ matto vindaty abhīpsitām
>
> By worshiping Me through the various methods prescribed in the Vedas
>   and tantras, one will gain from Me his desired perfection in both this
>   life and the next.

You also quoted some mantra quoted by Chaitanya Deva which is according to you is from  Brhan Naradiya purana as "there is no other way, no other way in the kaliyuga [for illumination].

a relevant shloka is also present in Srimad Bhagavata Purana as

> कलेर्दोषनिधे राजन्नस्ति ह्येको महान्गुणः |
>  कीर्तनादेव कृष्णस्य
>   मुक्तसङ्गः परं व्रजेत् ॥ [**12.3.51**](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/3/51/) ॥
>
> kaler doṣa-nidhe rājann asti hy eko mahān guṇaḥ
>  kīrtanād eva
>   kṛṣṇasya mukta-saṅgaḥ paraṁ vrajet
>
> My dear King, although Kali-yuga is an ocean of faults, there is still
>   one good quality about this age: **Simply by chanting the Hare Kṛṣṇa
>   mahā-mantra, one can become free from material bondage** and be
>   promoted to the transcendental kingdom.

What above shloka mean is Chanting the name of lord is the easiest and simplest of way with which all the people from any Varna and Ashrama  can  attain Moksha in Kaliyuga.But that does not mean it is the only way to achieve liberation in Kaliyuga and it is the great merit of this yuga  , the context is it's said that for  people of kali age it will be difficult to achieve liberation by other methods due to  effect of the Kali yuga and as said by Krishna himself in shloka no. 26 that  one can also achieve that  by vedic , tantric worship of supreme like sandhyavandanam and all other pujas etc. which are laid out by vedas  and tantra **and they are not redundant and futile.**

Comment: but kevalam and nastyaiva gatirantha do mean others are futile!

Answer (score 0):

Yes all else will be finally futile without हरेर्नाम, without bhakti/ love  for the lord.
हरेर्नाम हरेर्नाम हरेर्नाम केवलम्।
कलौ नास्त्येव नास्त्येव नास्त्येव गतिर्न्यथा।

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).