# Are women named after the goddess Sati?

Tags: name, sati-goddess

Like [Why people are named after Shantanu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11183/why-people-are-named-after-shantanu) , this is more specific than [Why is God's name used for people?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/why-is-gods-name-used-for-people) .

I heard about an Indian woman (possibly Hindu) with a given name of Sati the other day. Although familiar with people being named after other gods, I found that hard to believe, but checking the internet, [this site](http://www.sheknows.com/baby-names/name/sati) confirmed that Sati is an Indian female name.

Are women named after the goddess Sati, or is it just a coincidence (the name's only two syllables long, so it seems plausible)?

Comment: I think names like Sati, Vaidehi etc are avoided because of their tragic lives. Sati ended up committing suicide in Daksha's Yagna. But yeah https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sati_%28goddess%29 Sati is Indian Godess.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daksha Daksha Yagna

Comment: There are many names with two syllables... eg. Rati, Sita, Ram, Gita, Rita, Mira etc